# Creating a search application on Eclipse with GWT and Protege

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, protege

I would like to create a search application connected to a RDF/OWL database on Eclipse. I would like to use the Google Widget Toolkit plugin for the front end and the Protege plugin for the database side. Do I need some other "essential" tool for creating this application?

Answer (score 1):

In additional to GWT i can recommend you [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com), for actually searching [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) can be useful. And of course look at [Spring Framework](http://www.springframework.org/) and [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) for rapid development.

Give us more information about what you supposed to create?

Comment: Well, it's pretty much simple: I need to create browser-based application that is connected to a relational database integrated with RDF and OWL. As I know Java and I ussually use Eclipse, I thought the GWT+Protege approach would have been the most feasible.

Answer (score 0):

If you come from java GWT will feel instantly familiar. For the front end It abstracts away most of the quirks of java script development. 
In your case I would concentrate on the RPC asynchronous way and how will you transport data to the front end / serialization deserialization. GWT offers many different approaches you need to find out which solves your problem best.